# Google Map implementación de la API ¡Error!

Tags: javascript, google-maps, modal

Estoy intentando implementar este mapa de google en un modal pero al mostrar el modal el mapa no carga a no ser que inspecione la pagina.
La URL es: [http://94.177.214.187/genero1.php](http://94.177.214.187/genero1.php#)
El código es el siguiente:`

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"> Satifaction  | | <strong> The Rolling Stones</strong></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px;background:yellow"></div>


      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

```
function myMap() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
</script>
```

[image: texto en negrita]
Un saludo y Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pon la parte del javascript donde muestras el modal y donde llamas a la función myMap

Comment: Sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.

Comment: Donde haces el llamado a la funcion que carga el mapa?

Comment: <div id="map" style="width:101%;height:50%;background:yellow"></div>

Comment: he añadido  onclick="myMap"  pero me parece un poco chapuza y con un onload no carga. Si sabéis alguna otra manera.

Comment: Que código javascript utilizas para mostrar el modal al hacer click en algún sitio de la página? Sale cuando pinchas en la dirección que está en el pié de la página ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimina el `onclick` del `<div id="map">` dejándolo tal que así:

```
<div id="map" style="width:101%;height:50%;background:yellow"></div>
```

Debajo de la función myMap pon esto:

```
$( "div.modal.fade" ).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    myMap();
});
```

Lo he probado bajando tu web en local y funciona ok.

Comment: Gracias todo perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto... En vez de #modal pon el ID de tu modal.

```
 $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
          myMap();
    })
```